# saving file information one by one in arrayList

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop

I have an issue reading `.srt` file, whenever I am trying to read the file one by one and saving it in an arrayList to update the information to a jtable, the file is giving me only the first elements of the part of the file I need, but this is not the true issue the issue is the file is reading all the elements then add all the elements to one place I think in the array the following is code and input/output

```
public static ArrayList<String> getFileEndingTime() {   
    ArrayList<String> Lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String file = "tra.srt";
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf(':') != -1 && line.indexOf(',') != -1 && line.indexOf('0') != -1) { 
                //line.substring(18, 29);
                Lines.add(line.substring(18, 29));
                System.out.println(Lines);         
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    return Lines;
}
```

the input is the same as the output but it should not read the file from the beginning every time because of that all the column in the JTable have only the value  [0:00:04,080]

i think the right output is in order from top to down

```
 0:00:04,080
 0:00:07,040
 0:00:12,160
```

the output

```
[0:00:04,080]
[0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040]
[0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040, 0:00:12,160]
[0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040, 0:00:12,160, 0:00:13,720]
[0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040, 0:00:12,160, 0:00:13,720, 0:00:16,800]
[0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040, 0:00:12,160, 0:00:13,720, 0:00:16,800, 0:00:19,960]
```

file look like this

```
    1
00:00:01,600 --> 00:00:04,080
<b>Mr Magnussen, please state your
full name for the record.</b>

2
00:00:04,080 --> 00:00:07,040
Charles Augustus Magnussen.

3
00:00:08,960 --> 00:00:12,160
how would you describe your
influence over the Prime Minister?
```

the output in the JTable all this in one cell

```
 [0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040, 0:00:12,160, 0:00:13,720, 0:00:16,800, 0:00:19,960, 0:00:21,440, 0:00:28,520, 0:00:30,320, 0:00:32,920, 0:00:35,720, 0:00:39,400, 0:00:41,880, 0:00:45,640, 0:00:49,160, 0:00:54,800, 0:00:56,760, 0:01:00,160, 0:01:03,240, 0:01:05,360, 0:01:08,920, 0:01:11,600, 0:01:14,480, 0:01:15,680, 0:01:30,160, 0:02:45,120, 0:02:56,720, 0:02:58,760, 0:03:02,600, 0:03:04,040, 0:03:07,360, 0:03:12,400, 0:03:13,800, 0:03:16,360, 0:03:18,320, 0:03:20,480, 0:03:22,400, 0:03:27,320, 0:03:29,320, 0:03:30,760, 0:03:34,480, 0:03:40,240, 0:03:41,880, 0:03:44,720, 0:03:46,680, 0:03:48,840, 0:03:51,720, 0:03:53,440, 0:03:56,200, 0:03:57,880, 0:04:00,640, 0:04:01,960, 0:04:04,720, 0:04:07,800, 0:04:10,680, 0:04:12,080, 0:04:18,720, 0:04:21,560, 0:04:27,120, 0:04:28,960, 0:04:32,720, 0:04:37,800, 0:04:39,200, 0:04:41,360, 0:04:43,760, 0:04:45,440, 0:04:47,000, 0:04:49,320, 0:04:50,480, 0:04:52,520, 0:05:06,720, 0:05:14,160, 0:05:23,720, 0:05:25,120, 0:05:36,320, 0:05:38,920, 0:05:40,040, 0:05:42,840, 0:05:45,800, 0:05:48,120, 0:05:51,160, 0:05:52,760, 0:05:57,000, 0:06:00,480, 0:06:03,920, 0:06:06,080, 0:06:48,200, 0:06:50,600, 0:06:52,160, 0:06:55,240, 0:07:04,000, 0:07:08,080, 0:07:09,560, 0:07:11,600, 0:07:15,200, 0:07:16,520, 0:07:22,240, 0:07:25,760, 0:07:27,000, 0:07:28,880, 0:07:31,000, 0:07:33,960, 0:07:36,040, 0:07:37,760, 0:07:42,280, 0:07:47,240, 0:07:50,560, 0:07:54,280, 0:07:57,400, 0:07:58,800, 0:08:01,160, 0:08:03,400, 0:08:06,040, 0:08:08,560, 0:08:10,360, 0:08:12,360, 0:08:15,160, 0:08:17,160, 0:08:18,760, 0:08:29,880, 0:08:33,000, 0:08:35,000, 0:08:37,520, 0:08:39,320, 0:08:42,400, 0:08:43,880, 0:08:48,360, 0:08:53,160, 0:08:57,960, 0:09:02,480, 0:09:04,000, 0:09:07,440, 0:09:10,280, 0:09:13,120, 0:09:14,560, 0:09:17,960, 0:09:21,000, 0:09:23,520, 0:09:30,160, 0:09:31,640, 0:09:37,480, 0:09:40,360, 0:09:41,920, 0:09:43,240, 0:09:46,920, 0:09:49,000, 0:09:51,000, 0:09:53,120, 0:09:56,240, 0:09:58,480, 0:10:01,960, 0:10:03,480, 0:10:06,240, 0:10:20,560, 0:10:23,920, 0:10:30,080, 0:10:33,760, 0:10:35,200, 0:10:37,840, 0:10:40,240, 0:10:42,920, 0:10:45,280, 0:10:49,680, 0:10:54,440, 0:11:00,720, 0:11:03,760, 0:11:05,160, 0:11:07,680, 0:11:09,120, 0:11:10,960, 0:11:13,480, 0:11:15,400, 0:11:17,640, 0:11:20,040, 0:11:28,840, 0:11:32,360, 0:11:36,800, 0:11:39,560, 0:11:41,720, 0:11:43,240, 0:11:46,200, 0:11:49,400, 0:12:02,840, 0:12:05,120, 0:12:17,320, 0:12:19,440, 0:12:20,720, 0:12:24,160, 0:12:27,520, 0:12:29,960, 0:12:32,240, 0:12:34,200, 0:12:36,200, 0:12:39,040, 0:12:41,000, 0:12:43,520, 0:12:45,720, 0:12:48,360, 0:12:50,880, 0:12:54,680, 0:12:58,760, 0:13:01,440, 0:13:05,720, 0:13:07,640, 0:13:11,960, 0:13:14,440, 0:13:16,960, 0:13:19,280, 0:13:22,560, 0:13:25,320, 0:13:28,760, 0:13:32,480, 0:13:34,880, 0:13:36,400, 0:13:42,200, 0:13:43,920, 0:13:45,560, 0:13:48,280, 0:13:50,280, 0:13:51,400, 0:13:56,480, 0:13:58,760, 0:14:03,560, 0:14:05,760, 0:14:08,320, 0:14:11,280, 0:14:15,360, 0:14:21,240, 0:14:24,640, 0:14:26,920, 0:14:30,160, 0:14:33,600, 0:14:36,000, 0:14:38,560, 0:14:44,440, 0:14:46,640, 0:14:48,320, 0:14:51,760, 0:14:55,160, 0:15:00,880, 0:15:02,920, 0:15:06,680, 0:15:10,720, 0:15:13,080, 0:15:15,800, 0:15:17,640, 0:15:20,800, 0:15:28,200, 0:15:31,960, 0:15:35,560, 0:15:38,200, 0:15:41,360, 0:15:43,480, 0:15:45,040, 0:15:48,760, 0:15:51,000, 0:15:52,400, 0:15:55,720, 0:15:57,680, 0:15:59,280, 0:16:02,200, 0:16:05,440, 0:16:08,760, 0:16:11,920, 0:16:13,400, 0:16:17,040, 0:16:19,760, 0:16:22,240, 0:16:27,520, 0:16:29,640, 0:16:31,560, 0:16:34,000, 0:16:42,120, 0:16:44,560, 0:16:47,240, 0:16:50,160, 0:16:54,120, 0:16:56,960, 0:17:02,160, 0:17:07,120, 0:17:08,720, 0:17:11,720, 0:17:13,480, 0:17:15,400, 0:17:17,640, 0:17:19,960, 0:17:22,840, 0:17:24,440, 0:17:30,680, 0:17:32,880, 0:17:34,040, 0:17:38,840, 0:17:40,680, 0:17:43,040, 0:17:45,640, 0:17:49,680, 0:17:53,160, 0:18:04,280, 0:18:07,200, 0:18:09,840, 0:18:12,840, 0:18:15,640, 0:18:18,400, 0:18:19,720, 0:18:23,040, 0:18:36,560, 0:18:37,680, 0:18:40,840, 0:18:43,240, 0:18:45,400, 0:18:48,520, 0:18:51,640, 0:18:52,880, 0:18:54,440, 0:18:55,640, 0:18:57,760, 0:18:59,200, 0:19:02,840, 0:19:05,360, 0:19:08,320, 0:19:10,400, 0:19:13,280, 0:19:15,240, 0:19:21,120, 0:19:26,400, 0:19:29,560, 0:19:33,520, 0:19:35,880, 0:19:37,280, 0:19:45,560, 0:19:49,200, 0:19:51,000, 0:19:54,920, 0:20:00,360, 0:20:04,880, 0:20:07,160, 0:20:12,000, 0:20:15,120, 0:20:16,480, 0:20:19,600, 0:20:22,400, 0:20:27,280, 0:20:29,080, 0:20:31,920, 0:20:33,040, 0:20:37,840, 0:20:40,120, 0:20:42,520, 0:20:46,280, 0:20:49,480, 0:20:52,400, 0:20:55,560, 0:20:57,280, 0:20:59,920, 0:21:04,080, 0:21:07,240, 0:21:09,760, 0:21:13,000, 0:21:14,920, 0:21:16,600, 0:21:20,040, 0:21:26,080, 0:21:28,920, 0:21:30,960, 0:21:40,760, 0:21:48,560, 0:21:50,280, 0:21:52,840, 0:21:55,880, 0:22:00,440, 0:22:03,920, 0:22:06,560, 0:22:11,520, 0:22:13,480, 0:22:15,280, 0:22:18,600, 0:22:21,720, 0:22:23,360, 0:22:25,560, 0:22:28,480, 0:22:31,840, 0:22:37,160, 0:22:38,880, 0:22:41,640, 0:22:43,760, 0:22:45,680, 0:22:48,480, 0:22:51,160, 0:22:53,040, 0:22:56,960, 0:22:59,920, 0:23:01,640, 0:23:09,080, 0:23:19,760, 0:23:23,520, 0:23:25,800, 0:23:27,120, 0:23:33,120, 0:23:34,720, 0:23:35,800, 0:23:44,400, 0:23:46,440, 0:23:49,280, 0:23:50,960, 0:23:57,200, 0:23:58,600, 0:24:07,080, 0:24:14,520, 0:24:16,600, 0:24:19,400, 0:24:23,760, 0:24:26,880, 0:24:32,880, 0:24:34,520, 0:24:38,080, 0:24:39,960, 0:24:44,840, 0:24:49,200, 0:24:55,480, 0:24:57,160, 0:25:01,040, 0:25:04,080, 0:25:08,120, 0:25:11,160, 0:25:15,560, 0:25:18,440, 0:25:21,160, 0:25:27,160, 0:25:28,560, 0:25:33,640, 0:25:35,480, 0:25:37,080, 0:25:44,120, 0:25:49,400, 0:25:52,560, 0:25:56,480, 0:26:02,440, 0:26:04,960, 0:26:09,520, 0:26:11,320, 0:26:14,720, 0:26:18,240, 0:26:24,880, 0:26:27,360, 0:26:33,320, 0:26:34,600, 0:26:38,880, 0:26:40,840, 0:26:45,040, 0:26:52,360, 0:26:55,320, 0:26:59,360, 0:27:01,760, 0:27:05,400, 0:27:07,560, 0:27:11,120, 0:27:13,800, 0:27:17,720, 0:27:21,920, 0:27:25,120, 0:27:28,000, 0:27:30,240, 0:27:31,480, 0:27:35,080, 0:27:37,840, 0:27:41,000, 0:27:44,080, 0:27:49,040, 0:27:54,200, 0:28:10,880, 0:28:14,520, 0:28:16,520, 0:28:23,960, 0:28:26,560, 0:28:29,200, 0:28:33,480, 0:28:36,560, 0:28:40,120, 0:28:42,320, 0:28:46,000, 0:28:48,320, 0:28:50,960, 0:28:55,800, 0:28:59,400, 0:29:01,480, 0:29:05,120, 0:29:07,960, 0:29:10,760, 0:29:13,600, 0:29:16,160, 0:29:18,880, 0:29:21,680, 0:29:23,440, 0:29:25,920, 0:29:27,880, 0:29:32,000, 0:29:35,120, 0:29:37,440, 0:29:39,640, 0:29:42,720, 0:29:50,120, 0:29:52,320, 0:29:55,080, 0:29:59,040, 0:30:01,040, 0:30:03,680, 0:30:04,800, 0:30:10,280, 0:30:13,200, 0:30:15,960, 0:30:28,920, 0:30:30,480, 0:30:32,600, 0:30:35,880, 0:30:37,880, 0:30:41,280, 0:30:43,000, 0:31:02,040, 0:31:04,040, 0:31:08,520, 0:31:12,040, 0:31:16,600, 0:31:22,320, 0:31:25,480, 0:31:28,640, 0:31:31,440, 0:31:34,160, 0:31:44,160, 0:31:46,840, 0:31:48,160, 0:31:50,240, 0:31:52,080, 0:31:54,120, 0:31:55,760, 0:31:56,800, 0:32:00,040, 0:32:02,280, 0:32:03,520, 0:32:11,120, 0:32:12,240, 0:32:17,520, 0:32:28,160, 0:32:30,040, 0:32:33,000, 0:32:35,920, 0:32:38,880, 0:32:40,520, 0:32:45,000, 0:32:49,720, 0:32:52,960, 0:32:57,000, 0:33:08,200, 0:33:11,440, 0:33:14,720, 0:33:16,480, 0:33:20,640, 0:33:23,200, 0:33:25,320, 0:33:29,120, 0:33:33,040, 0:33:42,280, 0:33:57,320, 0:33:58,360, 0:34:00,960, 0:34:06,240, 0:34:07,960, 0:34:12,520, 0:34:15,880, 0:34:18,360, 0:34:19,960, 0:34:29,400, 0:34:31,160, 0:34:34,960, 0:34:43,960, 0:34:48,200, 0:34:50,920, 0:34:53,760, 0:34:56,680, 0:35:00,320, 0:35:04,920, 0:35:09,160, 0:35:11,840, 0:35:14,480, 0:35:18,320, 0:35:20,600, 0:35:22,960, 0:35:26,920, 0:35:29,600, 0:35:31,800, 0:35:33,360, 0:35:38,280, 0:35:40,040, 0:35:42,400, 0:35:44,560, 0:35:46,160, 0:35:48,640, 0:35:50,840, 0:35:54,280, 0:35:55,560, 0:35:57,760, 0:36:00,360, 0:36:02,600, 0:36:04,800, 0:36:11,360, 0:36:12,800, 0:36:14,320, 0:36:17,960, 0:36:20,000, 0:36:22,960, 0:36:25,200, 0:36:27,760, 0:36:31,120, 0:36:34,640, 0:36:35,960, 0:36:37,200, 0:36:54,960, 0:36:59,200, 0:37:02,160, 0:37:05,320, 0:37:06,760, 0:37:09,520, 0:37:13,920, 0:37:15,600, 0:37:22,240, 0:37:27,160, 0:37:29,760, 0:37:31,560, 0:37:33,600, 0:37:34,800, 0:37:36,720, 0:37:38,200, 0:37:41,080, 0:37:44,680, 0:37:46,360, 0:37:55,400, 0:37:58,640, 0:38:00,840, 0:38:03,120, 0:38:09,040, 0:38:13,520, 0:38:17,480, 0:38:21,280, 0:38:24,000, 0:38:32,920, 0:38:41,560, 0:38:44,720, 0:38:47,480, 0:38:51,960, 0:38:53,520, 0:38:57,080, 0:39:00,040, 0:39:01,520, 0:39:02,760, 0:39:03,880, 0:39:05,200, 0:39:06,800, 0:39:08,000, 0:39:10,240, 0:39:12,440, 0:39:15,440, 0:39:20,200, 0:39:23,720, 0:39:26,320, 0:39:30,120, 0:39:31,840, 0:39:35,080, 0:39:41,080, 0:39:44,480, 0:39:46,000, 0:39:58,720, 0:40:03,640, 0:40:05,960, 0:40:10,200, 0:40:14,280, 0:40:16,520, 0:40:19,480, 0:40:36,360, 0:40:38,000, 0:40:45,200, 0:41:37,520, 0:41:39,240, 0:41:42,600, 0:41:45,360, 0:41:46,760, 0:41:48,720, 0:41:49,960, 0:42:10,680, 0:42:14,200, 0:42:17,760, 0:42:25,000, 0:42:28,760, 0:42:32,200, 0:42:35,720, 0:42:46,040, 0:42:49,520, 0:42:51,880, 0:42:54,360, 0:42:57,560, 0:42:59,160, 0:43:01,640, 0:43:03,400, 0:43:06,560, 0:43:09,040, 0:43:10,520, 0:43:12,560, 0:43:15,320, 0:43:17,240, 0:43:19,640, 0:43:22,960, 0:43:25,040, 0:43:26,680, 0:43:30,200, 0:43:32,360, 0:43:34,560, 0:43:36,200, 0:43:38,760, 0:43:40,680, 0:43:43,000, 0:43:45,800, 0:43:47,080, 0:43:50,600, 0:43:52,160, 0:43:54,520, 0:43:56,640, 0:44:01,400, 0:44:05,560, 0:44:08,200, 0:44:10,600, 0:44:14,320, 0:44:16,840, 0:44:19,320, 0:44:22,040, 0:44:24,160, 0:44:45,520, 0:44:47,880, 0:44:49,240, 0:44:53,240, 0:44:57,720, 0:45:05,840, 0:45:16,640, 0:45:18,840, 0:45:21,040, 0:45:24,480, 0:45:31,800, 0:45:35,880, 0:45:37,560, 0:45:40,040, 0:45:44,360, 0:45:47,360, 0:45:49,000, 0:45:51,280, 0:45:53,360, 0:45:54,840, 0:45:57,120, 0:45:58,760, 0:46:04,520, 0:46:06,160, 0:46:07,440, 0:46:11,640, 0:46:13,880, 0:46:16,760, 0:46:18,720, 0:46:21,600, 0:46:25,360, 0:46:27,680, 0:46:30,160, 0:46:32,920, 0:46:37,200, 0:46:39,520, 0:46:42,520, 0:46:46,720, 0:46:50,680, 0:46:53,520, 0:46:56,080, 0:47:01,800, 0:47:06,120, 0:47:08,560, 0:47:11,880, 0:47:19,240, 0:47:20,920, 0:47:28,080, 0:47:31,400, 0:47:35,080, 0:47:42,360, 0:47:44,320, 0:47:48,080, 0:47:53,240, 0:47:56,600, 0:48:00,160, 0:48:02,240, 0:48:06,080, 0:48:08,280, 0:48:11,160, 0:48:13,600, 0:48:15,800, 0:48:16,960, 0:48:18,640, 0:48:23,120, 0:48:26,280, 0:48:28,360, 0:48:32,360, 0:48:35,240, 0:48:37,760, 0:48:40,280, 0:48:42,600, 0:48:44,440, 0:48:48,240, 0:48:54,240, 0:48:55,840, 0:48:58,800, 0:49:03,960, 0:49:07,360, 0:49:13,520, 0:49:18,000, 0:49:23,120, 0:49:27,280, 0:49:31,120, 0:49:35,800, 0:49:38,360, 0:49:41,280, 0:49:44,040, 0:49:47,600, 0:49:49,360, 0:49:51,920, 0:49:54,560, 0:49:57,000, 0:49:59,080, 0:50:01,800, 0:50:06,040, 0:50:08,360, 0:50:11,080, 0:50:14,680, 0:50:16,760, 0:50:18,280, 0:50:21,320, 0:50:37,040, 0:50:43,160, 0:50:45,200, 0:50:57,960, 0:50:59,920, 0:51:05,560, 0:51:10,960, 0:51:17,240, 0:51:21,840, 0:51:25,600, 0:51:28,240, 0:51:30,720, 0:51:35,280, 0:51:40,360, 0:51:41,560, 0:51:45,800, 0:52:04,440, 0:52:20,120, 0:52:23,000, 0:52:25,200, 0:52:28,760, 0:52:30,760, 0:52:33,640, 0:52:35,400, 0:52:37,920, 0:52:40,200, 0:52:42,920, 0:52:45,080, 0:52:46,720, 0:52:47,960, 0:52:49,640, 0:52:53,560, 0:52:57,960, 0:52:59,360, 0:53:01,080, 0:53:04,160, 0:53:06,680, 0:53:08,760, 0:53:10,600, 0:53:12,680, 0:53:14,800, 0:53:17,960, 0:53:22,600, 0:53:25,880, 0:53:32,920, 0:53:36,280, 0:53:39,360, 0:53:41,440, 0:53:43,560, 0:53:46,720, 0:53:48,800, 0:53:54,440, 0:53:56,000, 0:54:01,640, 0:54:04,360, 0:54:08,120, 0:54:12,120, 0:54:14,400, 0:54:21,040, 0:54:25,400, 0:54:27,280, 0:54:31,240, 0:54:32,720, 0:54:44,160, 0:54:47,520, 0:54:53,480, 0:55:08,200, 0:55:14,120, 0:55:16,520, 0:55:20,160, 0:55:21,680, 0:55:23,000, 0:55:27,000, 0:55:28,360, 0:55:32,440, 0:55:34,960, 0:55:37,720, 0:55:42,680, 0:55:43,720, 0:55:46,560, 0:55:49,280, 0:55:53,080, 0:55:54,640, 0:55:57,320, 0:55:59,360, 0:56:01,680, 0:56:04,080, 0:56:06,080, 0:56:08,960, 0:56:11,360, 0:56:13,880, 0:56:17,520, 0:56:19,440, 0:56:22,440, 0:56:24,080, 0:56:26,480, 0:56:30,240, 0:56:34,560, 0:56:39,440, 0:56:41,080, 0:56:43,480, 0:56:49,080, 0:56:53,600, 0:57:01,880, 0:57:05,960, 0:57:08,560, 0:57:10,520, 0:57:12,760, 0:57:16,280, 0:57:19,640, 0:57:23,360, 0:57:27,400, 0:57:32,720, 0:57:35,920, 0:57:44,120, 0:57:45,480, 0:57:47,560, 0:57:51,640, 0:57:54,000, 0:57:55,040, 0:57:59,640, 0:58:01,600, 0:58:34,440, 0:58:39,440, 0:58:45,600, 0:58:50,000, 0:59:00,280, 0:59:04,440, 0:59:10,560, 0:59:12,920, 0:59:14,840, 0:59:18,040, 0:59:20,840, 0:59:29,920, 0:59:34,240, 0:59:37,280, 0:59:38,840, 0:59:41,080, 0:59:44,000, 0:59:46,880, 0:59:49,160, 0:59:52,480, 0:59:53,840, 0:59:55,640, 0:59:58,720, 1:00:01,160, 1:00:04,240, 1:00:05,480, 1:00:09,680, 1:00:13,160, 1:00:16,840, 1:00:26,080, 1:00:30,360, 1:00:33,400, 1:00:34,680, 1:00:37,000, 1:00:39,280, 1:00:42,520, 1:00:46,000, 1:00:50,720, 1:00:55,840, 1:01:01,600, 1:01:15,800, 1:01:21,720, 1:01:25,840, 1:01:28,520, 1:01:30,640, 1:01:33,320, 1:01:43,040, 1:01:47,560, 1:01:54,680, 1:01:56,160, 1:01:57,760, 1:02:00,040, 1:02:01,560, 1:02:06,920, 1:02:09,000, 1:02:10,440, 1:02:13,600, 1:02:15,720, 1:02:18,720, 1:02:20,360, 1:02:22,080, 1:02:23,800, 1:02:26,960, 1:02:29,600, 1:02:34,200, 1:02:37,680, 1:02:39,280, 1:02:42,840, 1:02:45,000, 1:02:46,240, 1:03:01,400, 1:03:09,280, 1:03:11,360, 1:03:16,360, 1:03:24,840, 1:03:29,280, 1:03:31,920, 1:03:37,440, 1:03:42,840, 1:03:43,960, 1:03:47,480, 1:03:57,960, 1:04:03,240, 1:04:06,720, 1:04:09,520, 1:04:11,360, 1:04:19,600, 1:04:21,000, 1:04:24,000, 1:04:25,240, 1:04:29,640, 1:04:31,440, 1:04:32,680, 1:04:35,080, 1:04:40,120, 1:04:43,720, 1:04:45,200, 1:04:47,240, 1:04:49,840, 1:04:52,520, 1:04:54,440, 1:04:58,840, 1:05:01,920, 1:05:06,480, 1:05:09,680, 1:05:11,080, 1:05:12,440, 1:05:22,200, 1:05:24,240, 1:05:25,640, 1:05:30,320, 1:05:33,720, 1:05:36,520, 1:05:39,040, 1:05:43,200, 1:05:45,480, 1:05:48,720, 1:05:53,600, 1:05:54,920, 1:05:58,480, 1:06:01,720, 1:06:05,280, 1:06:09,320, 1:06:14,360, 1:06:18,120, 1:06:20,120, 1:06:27,320, 1:06:31,640, 1:06:35,200, 1:06:38,520, 1:06:41,600, 1:06:42,840, 1:06:45,360, 1:06:50,120, 1:06:56,720, 1:06:59,840, 1:07:02,200, 1:07:05,560, 1:07:06,680, 1:07:09,720, 1:07:11,000, 1:07:14,040, 1:07:24,200, 1:07:27,800, 1:07:31,120, 1:07:32,160, 1:07:38,520, 1:07:39,960, 1:07:45,760, 1:07:50,160, 1:07:52,440, 1:07:55,160, 1:07:59,800, 1:08:04,800, 1:08:08,520, 1:08:15,880, 1:08:20,720, 1:08:27,360, 1:08:34,960, 1:08:40,920, 1:08:58,160, 1:09:00,920, 1:09:14,040, 1:09:26,920, 1:09:30,520, 1:09:32,280, 1:09:33,520, 1:09:38,520, 1:09:39,880, 1:09:45,440, 1:09:54,000, 1:09:55,440, 1:09:59,720, 1:10:06,840, 1:10:08,320, 1:10:10,240, 1:10:12,640, 1:10:16,400, 1:10:19,720, 1:10:22,400, 1:10:24,800, 1:10:28,040, 1:10:31,960, 1:10:34,480, 1:11:34,520, 1:11:42,800, 1:11:44,560, 1:11:48,160, 1:11:51,080, 1:11:55,360, 1:11:58,480, 1:12:01,920, 1:12:08,240, 1:12:11,000, 1:12:15,440, 1:12:18,920, 1:12:28,720, 1:12:32,520, 1:12:36,480, 1:12:38,680, 1:12:44,800, 1:12:47,760, 1:12:50,640, 1:12:53,880, 1:12:57,760, 1:13:00,880, 1:13:06,280, 1:13:10,640, 1:13:12,160, 1:13:18,560, 1:13:21,680, 1:13:26,720, 1:13:29,360, 1:13:33,120, 1:13:37,240, 1:13:39,760, 1:13:42,400, 1:13:46,720, 1:13:59,120, 1:14:03,760, 1:14:06,680, 1:14:10,560, 1:14:14,480, 1:14:18,120, 1:14:20,720, 1:14:22,640, 1:14:27,200, 1:14:29,960, 1:14:35,520, 1:14:40,360, 1:14:44,800, 1:14:49,600, 1:14:52,480, 1:14:57,480, 1:15:00,880, 1:15:04,560, 1:15:12,160, 1:15:26,240, 1:15:29,120, 1:15:45,040, 1:15:50,120, 1:15:54,560, 1:16:00,000, 1:16:03,560, 1:16:08,640, 1:16:15,360, 1:16:22,040, 1:16:25,000, 1:16:34,280, 1:16:43,840, 1:16:48,280, 1:16:50,480, 1:16:56,560, 1:17:02,160, 1:17:13,400, 1:17:15,800, 1:17:22,880, 1:17:27,080, 1:17:28,880, 1:17:32,600, 1:17:33,720, 1:17:36,560, 1:17:41,360, 1:17:43,520, 1:17:46,240, 1:17:48,360, 1:17:51,440, 1:17:53,360, 1:17:56,240, 1:17:58,600, 1:18:00,640, 1:18:05,800, 1:18:07,600, 1:18:11,680, 1:18:14,280, 1:18:29,720, 1:18:31,160, 1:18:33,320, 1:18:36,640, 1:18:40,240, 1:18:42,600, 1:18:46,320, 1:18:55,680, 1:19:00,720, 1:19:03,800, 1:19:08,720, 1:19:21,040, 1:19:23,320, 1:19:25,480, 1:19:29,480, 1:19:34,960, 1:19:41,120, 1:19:46,520, 1:19:49,720, 1:19:53,120, 1:20:02,200, 1:20:05,280, 1:20:09,040, 1:20:12,160, 1:20:15,240, 1:20:18,400, 1:20:19,720, 1:20:22,720, 1:20:26,080, 1:20:33,280, 1:20:37,800, 1:20:50,840, 1:20:53,000, 1:20:57,240, 1:20:59,400, 1:21:01,640, 1:21:06,040, 1:21:08,960, 1:21:11,640, 1:21:12,920, 1:21:16,000, 1:21:19,840, 1:21:24,560, 1:21:28,480, 1:21:34,040, 1:21:36,160, 1:21:41,320, 1:21:43,280, 1:21:46,440, 1:21:48,560, 1:21:50,560, 1:21:53,720, 1:21:55,720, 1:21:58,600, 1:22:07,840, 1:22:38,280, 1:22:42,000, 1:22:54,160, 1:22:57,400, 1:23:00,160, 1:23:04,520, 1:23:11,200, 1:23:15,320, 1:23:16,520, 1:23:19,560, 1:23:24,440, 1:23:28,160, 1:23:31,520, 1:23:37,240, 1:23:39,160, 1:23:44,280, 1:23:59,760, 1:24:02,880, 1:24:05,000, 1:24:13,320, 1:24:15,240, 1:24:25,960, 1:24:30,000, 1:24:31,120, 1:24:33,640, 1:24:37,800, 1:24:39,200, 1:24:46,400, 1:24:49,000, 1:24:50,360, 1:24:53,400, 1:24:56,280, 1:24:58,320, 1:25:01,880, 1:25:06,120, 1:25:10,640, 1:25:14,080, 1:25:15,280, 1:25:17,720, 1:25:24,200, 1:25:26,800, 1:25:28,200, 1:25:33,400, 1:25:34,480, 1:25:39,080, 1:25:51,160, 1:25:52,600, 1:25:56,520, 1:26:02,480, 1:26:07,080, 1:26:08,280, 1:26:10,520, 1:26:12,040, 1:26:20,520, 1:27:10,200, 1:27:13,160, 1:27:18,760, 1:27:22,280, 1:27:23,840, 1:27:27,080, 1:27:28,760, 1:27:31,600, 1:27:33,080, 1:27:35,000, 1:27:38,360, 1:27:41,440, 1:27:47,600, 1:27:51,680, 1:27:54,120, 1:27:55,600, 1:27:57,800, 1:28:00,640, 1:28:02,760, 1:28:05,120, 1:28:08,720, 1:28:12,320, 1:28:13,880, 1:28:16,480, 1:28:18,360, 1:28:20,360, 1:28:24,640, 1:28:28,120, 1:29:06,480]
```

the way of insert data to jtable

```
    Object[][] data = new Object [ReadFile.maxLine()][COLUMN];
    ArrayList <String > Dumy = new ArrayList<String>() ;

  //String [] countries = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

 Dumy = ReadFile.ArraylineLengths();


    for(int i = 0; i < Dumy.size(); i++) 
    {
    data[i][0]  = Dumy.get(i);
    }


    for(int i=0;i < ReadFile.maxLine();i++){ 
         // data[i][0] = ReadFile.lineLengths();
            data[i][1] = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime() ;
            data[i][2] = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime();
            data[i][3] = ReadFile.readSubtitles() ;
    } 
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
```

the final output, all the timing in the file in one cell and it show only the first end time because the cell are not big

[image: the final picture]

Comment: what exactly is the issue? Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: You are not traversing the list while placing the data in `JTable`. You need to. Please post the code how put the data in `JTable`

Comment: didn't understand your issue, is your problem about not getting values like `00:00:08,960` ?

Comment: instead of `System.out.println(Lines);`, try `System.out.println(line.substring(18, 29));`. Now you're printing the whole list, not just the last added element.

Comment: there is no issue with Sys.. because this going to be deleted the issue is with getting only the first value from the file

Comment: you can take a look now about the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure about what you are doing but first you should improve your detection of the line you want to find. As it is :

```
if (line.indexOf(':') != -1 && line.indexOf(',') != -1 && line.indexOf('0') != -1)
```

If you have a subtitle like : `hi : Mister 007, how are you ?` your program won't work properly because it will be detected as a time line.

Maybe by adding `-->` as a pattern to find or the best would be to detect the line number and then you know it's the next line ;)

Ps : For your problem I will edit this post when I understand your problem but this link (code in PHP) seems to be pretty well done and easy to translate in Java : [parsing .srt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659118/parsing-srt-files)

By any chance is this what you want ?

```
public static ArrayList<String> getFileEndingTime() {   
    ArrayList<String> Lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String file = "tra.srt";
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf(':') != -1 && line.indexOf(',') != -1 && line.indexOf('0') != -1) { 
                Lines.add(line.substring(18, 29));
                System.out.println(Lines.get(i++));         
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    return Lines;
}
```

output :

```
0:00:04,080
0:00:07,040
0:00:12,160
```

it's your code, I just changed the `System.out.println`

your actual output is like this because it's java's way to show you an array, it shows you all the item in your array :

```
[0:00:04,080] ==> [item1]
[0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040] ==> [item1, item2]
[0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040, 0:00:12,160] ==> [item1, item2, item3] 
etc.
```

UPDATE :

```
for(int i=0;i < ReadFile.maxLine();i++){ 
     // data[i][0] = ReadFile.lineLengths();
        data[i][1] = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime() ;
        data[i][2] = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime();
        data[i][3] = ReadFile.readSubtitles() ;
}
```

should become :

```
ArrayList<String> starts = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime();
ArrayList<String> ends = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime();
ArrayList<String> subs = ReadFile.readSubtitles();

for(int i=0;i < ReadFile.maxLine();i++){ 
        data[i][1] = starts.get(i);
        data[i][2] = ends.get(i);
        data[i][3] = subs.get(i);
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem ;) don't forget to validate the answer if it works ;)

Comment: i have the 3 weak only to finish this so i can't study regex from 0 but my issue is when the code read the file it is start by reading 00:00:01,600 then it read the 00:00:01,600 again then the next line so when ever i update the jtable it only show this value 00:00:01,600 the first one all over the jtable

Comment: Can you give me the output of your `data` ? I think you data[x][0] should be `null` but with `""` instead.

Comment: look at the line "the output in the JTable all this in one cell" this the output in the jtable

Comment: that's not what I want to see, I already know this is good so can you show me the output of what is inside the data[][] just before `DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);`

Comment: `for(int i=0;i < ReadFile.maxLine();i++){ 
         // data[i][0] = ReadFile.lineLengths();
            data[i][1] = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime() ;
            data[i][2] = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime();
            data[i][3] = ReadFile.readSubtitles() ;
            system.out.println(data[i]);
    }`

Comment: [Ljava.lang.Object;@3dd8835d
[Ljava.lang.Object;@51986e63
[Ljava.lang.Object;@6e774f6e
[Ljava.lang.Object;@5afff76a

Comment: lol not what I wanted, change it to `system.out.println(data[i][0] +" "+data[i][1] +" "+data[i][2] +" "+data[i][3]);`

Comment: '1 [] [0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040, 0:00:12,160, 0:00:13,720, 0:00:16,800, 0:00:19,960, 0:00:21,440, 0:00:28,520, 0:00:30,320, 0:00:32,920, 1:29:06,480] <b>Mr Magnussen, please 54545 statse your
full name for the 454 record.</b>'

Comment: it is longer than that but i minimized it, i need only 0:00:04:080 to be with number 1

Comment: do u like to add any idea

Comment: from here I think you can find your answer. Is the output what you wanted ? If not then what is wrong ?

Comment: :) i was here the wrong is 0:00:04,080, 0:00:07,040, 0:00:12,160, 0:00:13,720.. why all file next to the number one in one cell i will upload the picture

Comment: Oki I finally understand what you want XD
what you are doing wrong is that you call the method every time and also that you put all the array in the data for each line :) 
You have to select just the index you want